# Any data-driven open source JEE5 EJB3+JSF Sample Project out there?

Tags: java, open-source, jsf, jakarta-ee, java-ee-5

I am looking for an open source project that uses EJB3 as backend and JSF as frontend. It should *not* be a tutorial but a real application that real people are using.

The application should be data-driven, i.e. the following aspects are fundamental and make 80% or more of the application.

- form-based (many input forms)
- table views, master/detail, etc.
- CRUD (create/read/update/delete)-Operations have been implemented
- support for relations: 1:1, 1:n
- JPA Entity Beans + EJB 3 Stateless Session Beans for Facade
- no JBoss Seam

Typical applications are CRM / ERP projects where people work a lot with lists, tables, and forms. But any other "administrative" application should be OK, too.

I know petstore, but that application isn't form-based. petstore is a end-user application. I am looking for backend-user applications.

Something like Microsofts AdventureWorks series, but with EJB3+JSF...
Something like SugarCRM, but with EJB3+JSF...

I've googled *a lot*... with no results :-(

- @Matthew: the samples provided with NetBeans are too simple.
- @JB: It should be a real application. Not a "how to do EJB+JSF" application.
- @50-50: voted down because of seam
- @Kariem: I can't use seam, AppFuse hasn't EJB Session Beans

Comment: I guess no one is encouraged to answer posts where you get downvoted not just for being wrong or off topic, but also for not being good enough.

Comment: Eh, I'm guessing it's just because there doesn't seem to be anything out there that's been done in JEE/JSF.  :-(  I'm in the same boat, trying to write an app, but keep getting stuck on stupid little problems that I can't solve.  Documentation is a bit short on some areas, tutorials don't cover anything useful, and there just aren't any good samples/open source to look at.  If there are, apparently Google doesn't index them...  :-/

Answer (score 2):

Seam examples are quite good. They are stand-alone projects, that you may deploy out of the box.

Comment: Too bad the link on their website that claims to point to samples is broken.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain, this is not an answer, as much as an observation that the Java World in general suffers from the lack of good applications that go beyond the tutorial. Some of the sample .NET applications are very good and show interesting techniques, while solving small enough problems that the novice can wrap their heads around the entire application and see "real code" doing "real things".

I have not looked at the Seam examples, so they may well be an exception, but having sample applications, particularly the CRUD, Query, Report style back office applications you're talking about, are a great help to folks and I wish there were more in the Java community.

Comment: For how many bazillion JEE programmers are supposedly out there, it just doesn't seem like there's a community at all.  There's a few isolated people I've run across that do it and help n00bs, but no supporting community like .NET has.

Comment: I can't comment on the .NET community, but the Java communities I've been involved with have been very helpful and useful. In one sense, though, the Java community is shrinking now that most of the technologies have been stable for some years now. Many people participate in communities to learn, and some give back while learning, but once they've learned, they leave the community. With the maturity of the Java platform as a whole, less people are learning and thus fewer are participating.

Answer (score 0):

You might poke around at these real world JSF apps and see if any of them have their source available: [RealWorldJsfLinks](http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Projects/RealWorldJSFLinks)

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure is it 100% what your looking for, **but check out the built in example that comes packaged with NetBeans 6.1**. It uses JSF/EJB3/ApacheDerby. I played around with it for like 20 minutes and thought it was pretty cool as a simple/starter JavaEE application to learn from.

Answer (score -1):

I have to second jb's comment: The seam examples are great and can be put to use. The [Seam Homepage](http://www.seamframework.org/) uses the Seam Wiki from the examples (that application alone fulfills all the outlined criteria). Other examples in the distribution: *Hotel Booking*, *DVD Store*, and a *Blog*. The [documentation](http://docs.jboss.com/seam/latest/reference/en-US/html/tutorial.html) contains quite some information on the special parts of the examples.

The "problem" might be that Seam covers a lot of the details you'd usually have to do in a traditional EJB3/JSF application. You might want to have a look at [AppFuse](http://appfuse.org/) or [AppFuse Light](https://appfuse-light.dev.java.net/). They have one application with examples using different technologies, including EJB3 (JPA only) and JSF. The examples are not as sophisticated (don't really fulfill your criteria), but contain a lot of useful stuff.